# Disable "Cut", "Copy" & "Paste" in wijmo spreadjs ipad

Tags: jquery, ipad, spreadjs

I am loading xlsx files in the iPad using wijmo spreadJs framework. When i select a cell i am be to see "Cut", "Copy" & "Paste" option be default. I want to disable it.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable all the entire spreadsheet

```
spreadsheet.setIsProtected(true);
```

Then you won't be able to perform any action, just visualize